# not able to access api running out of istio service mesh

Tags: kubernetes, proxy, istio, servicemesh

I am running service mesh using minikube and trying to access api running outside the minikube using fortio :

```
kubectl exec "$FORTIO_POD" -c fortio -- /usr/bin/fortio load -c 1 -qps 0 -n 1 -loglevel debug http://localhost:3000
```

but this is giving me error :

```
dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3000: connect: connection refused
```

Below is the service entry and destinationRule object I have created :

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: localhost
spec:
  hosts:
  - localhost
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
  - number: 3000
    name: http
    protocol: HTTP
  resolution: STATIC
  endpoints:
  - address: 127.0.0.1
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: localhost
spec:
  host: localhost
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: DISABLE
      sni: localhost.local
```

Comment: Could you try with `localhost.somedomain`, for example `localhost.com` as your ServiceEntry and DestinationRule host? AFAIK ServiceEntry might not work with just `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying here is to access an API which is hosted in the host system from within Minikube.
You can't expect to connect to host system just by creating a localhost service entry in istio.
For minikube host access you need to use `host.minikube.internal`

Refer this link:
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/host-access/